# SQL query with NOT IN and WHERE relation with GUIDs

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-delete, sql-null

There are two tables `Document` and `DocumentPos`. In `Document` there is column `GUID` and in `DocumentPos` is column `DocumentGUID` which refers to table `Document`.

> I want to have every row in `DocumentPos` where its `DocumentGUID` has now
>   row in `Documents'` `GUID`.

I've this query which returns 0 rows:

```
select *
FROM             Document d,
                 DocumentPos dp
WHERE            d.GUID = dp.DocumentGUID
AND              dp.DocumentGUID NOT IN (
                 SELECT d.GUID
                 FROM Document
)
```

But when when I execute `select * from documentpos` it returns for example a row with `DocumentGUID`= `B479BCB72334424DAC1B7CC26880DAB8`. And this `DocumentGUID` is `NOT IN` table `Document` as a `GUID`.

But `select * from Document where GUID = 'B479BCB72334424DAC1B7CC26880DAB8'` returns 0 rows.

I want to build the query like this because it should become a `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE           dp
FROM             Document d,
                 DocumentPos dp
WHERE            d.GUID = cp.DocmentGUID
AND              dp.DocumentGUID NOT IN (
                 SELECT d.GUID
                 FROM Document
)
```

Second question what I'm also wondering:

> Why is in the brackets not `FROM d` possible and only `FROM Document`?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOT IN` is tricky with `NULL`s. You can use `NOT EXISTS` instead, which is null-safe. Also, I cannot see why you need to bring in the `document` table in the outer query.

I think that you want:

```
select *
from documentpos dp
where not exists (
    select 1 from document d where d.guid = dp.documentguid
)
```

You can turn this to a delete statement as follows:

```
delete dp
from documentpos dp
where not exists (
    select 1 from document d where d.guid = dp.documentguid
)
```

Answer (score 2):

All i could understand is that you want to remove data from *DocumentPos* table which does not exist in Main table *Document*. You can use following query:

```
DELETE dp FROM DocumentPos dp
left join Document d on d.GUID = dp.DocumentGUID
where d.GUID is null
```