# How to add NOT EXISTS in SQL INSERT INTO query with SELECT and LinkedServer

Tags: sql-server, insert, linked-server

There are two tables `Document` and `DocumentPos`. In `Document` there is column `GUID` and in `DocumentPos` is column `DocumentGUID` which refers to table `Document`.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DocumentPos]
           (
            [GUID]
           ,[DocumentGUID]
           ,[Number]
           ,[Price]
           )
     SELECT
           cqdp.GUID,
           cqdp.DocumentGUID,           
           cqdp.Number
           cqdp.Price
FROM [sqlserver\instance].[testdb].[dbo].[documentpos] cqdp
INNER JOIN [sqlserver\instance].[testdb].[dbo].[document] cqd ON cqd.GUID = cqdp.DocumentGUID
WHERE cqdp.DocumentGUID  IN (
SELECT GUID
FROM [sqlserver\instance].[testdb].[dbo].[document]
) 
AND NOT EXISTS 
(
...
)
```

But how can I include `NOT EXISTS` which avoids that the query trys to insert values which already exist on column `GUID`? I want to add a check if the `GUID` already exists in `DocumentPos` which I want to include from `[sqlserver\instance].[testdb].[dbo].[documentpos`].

Comment: Isn't this effectively the same as you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59192076/sql-query-with-not-in-and-where-relation-with-guids)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
...
FROM [sqlserver\instance].[testdb].[dbo].[documentpos] cqdp
JOIN [sqlserver\instance].[testdb].[dbo].[document] cqd 
  ON cqd.GUID = cqdp.DocumentGUID
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1
  FROM [dbo].[DocumentPos] AS dp
  WHERE dp.[GUID] = cqdp.[GUID]
);
```

Just linking the source to the target on the Guid.

That extra criteria with the `IN` seems pointless, since the `INNER JOIN` already forces that filter.